# How to show row number in LongListSelector

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, longlistselector

I just want to use a `TextBlock` to show the current row number (items number, it should be 1,2,3,...,ItemsSource.Count.) in a `LongListSelector`.  Let's say I have 3 instance elements in my ItemsSource.  What I want to do is: for item1, the `TextBlock` should show 1, item2, show 2, item3, show 3.  I know I can Bind `TextBlock.Text` to a data which is 1, 2, 3...  but I think there should be an easy way to realize this.  Any suggestions?  Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by a current row number? The row number of the tapped item?

Comment: hi @igrali I updated my questions.  For your concern, I mean: (items number, it should be 1,2,3,...,ItemsSource.Count)

Comment: while creating list you can set the index

Answer (score 0):

xaml:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ListItemsCount}"/>
```

code:

```
public int ListItemsCount
{
  get
  {
    return ItemsSource.Count;
  }
  set
  {
  }
}
```

If I understand you correctly.

Comment: hi @crea7or, thank you for your response.  I don't think this is what I mean.  Let's say I have 3 instance in my ItemsSource, by your method I guess for every items it'll always show 3.  What I want is: for item1, show 1, item2, show 2, item3, show 3.  Any idea?  Thank you

Comment: So, you need selected item index?

Answer (score 0):

You could add the items manually and pass the index in that moment. Something like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<items.Count; i++) {
    items[i].Index = i;
    List.Add(items[i]);
}
```

You can bind to the Index property to show the index.